# How to set Gtk Icon Theme with PYGtk?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

How can I set the global system icon theme with Python (PYGtk 3)?

This is returning the current Icon Theme in the system. It works perfect.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gio, GLib
print(Gtk.Settings.get_default().get_property("gtk-icon-theme-name"))
```

But I can't set it. I tried this, but without a result:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject, Gio, GLib
Gtk.Settings.get_default().set_property("gtk-icon-theme-name", "Numix")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to check that the directory of the theme you want exists in `/path/to/Python/x.x/Lib/site-packages/gnome/share/themes/`.

Then, before the program/script initialises the Gtk Window, set the theme to use:

```
from sys import stderr, exit
try:
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject, Gio, GLib
except (ImportError, ImportWarning):
    stderr.write("Could not import GTK. Please install it.")

class HelloWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Settings.get_default().set_property("gtk-icon-theme-name", "Numix")
        Gtk.Settings.get_default().set_property("gtk-theme-name", "MS-Windows-XP")
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World")
        ...
```